# Tableau - sorting not working properly (using aggregate sum)

Tags: data-visualization, data-science, tableau-api

Can someone help me how can I sort or get the top 10 of the data by country? Tableau sorts it based on aggregate sum which I don't want. The problem happens when I put the report date on Pages.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UczIw.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean you want the top 10 to be based on the count across all dates, not just the one date that is currently selected in pages?

Comment: Yes that is correct. So this top 10 will be changing as the date goes by when I use page control. Is this possible?